# Python list filtering with arguments

Tags: python, list, filter, functional-programming

Is there a way in python to call filter on a list where the filtering function has a number of arguments bound during the call. For example is there a way to do something like this:

```
>> def foo(a,b,c):
    return a < b and b < c

>> myList = (1,2,3,4,5,6)

>> filter(foo(a=1,c=4),myList)
>> (2,3)
```

This is to say is there a way to call foo such that a=1, c=4, and b gets bound to the values in myList?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can create a closure for this purpose:

```
def makefilter(a, c):
   def myfilter(x):
       return a < x < c
   return myfilter

filter14 = makefilter(1, 4)

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
filter(filter14, myList)
>>> [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 69):

One approach is to use `lambda`:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     return a < b and b < c
... 
>>> myTuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> filter(lambda x: foo(1, x, 4), myTuple)
(2, 3)
```

Another is to use [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> filter(partial(foo, 1, c=4), myTuple)
(2, 3)
```

Comment: +1 for lambda. And also, if you want to use lambda without arguments, just use `filter(lambda: foo(1,4), myTuple)`.

Comment: The lambda solution should be the chosen answer. It's a lot cleaner if you have to have the filter in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(a,c):
    return lambda b : a < b and b < c

myList = (1,2,3,4,5,6)

g = filter(foo(1,4),myList)
```