# im trying to convert my function into a lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I want to convert this function into a lambda but idk what am i doing wrong.

```
temperatures=[10,20,30,11,22,33]

def check_weather(temp,low,high):
    if temp in range(low,high):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(list(filter(lambda weather,low,high: True if weather in range(low,high) else False,temperatures)))
```

the error is:

> TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'low' and 'high'

Comment: Where did you use `temp`? I assume `weather` here is `temp`

Comment: And where do values of `low`, `high` should come from?

Comment: Can you please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Returning `True` or `False` based on a boolean value is unnecessarily complex.  Just return the boolean value itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a function with two arguments to filter() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609935/passing-a-function-with-two-arguments-to-filter-in-python) - while your function takes three arguments the concept is the same. - additionaly: [Python list filtering with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045754/python-list-filtering-with-arguments) ... [How to get filter to work with a lambda taking multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391043/how-to-get-filter-to-work-with-a-lambda-taking-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lambda. If this were possible, you could use the function as an object

```
def check_weather(temp,low,high):
    return low <= temp <= high

print(list(filter(check_weather, weathers)))
```

However, the filter function only passes one parameter to the internal filter function

You could define a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)  if you wanted to accomplish this, however it's not clear how you're assigning the low and high values

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign low and high values first